# How do I force a .change() event within Datatables?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery DataTables and some custom code to build a comparison basket for a site.

I know `.change()` forces a change event but when I am doing this from within DataTables it doesn't seem to work.

Here is the offending code:

```
table.on('change', '[type="checkbox"]', function () {
~
~
~
removeCtrl.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var removal_id = $(this).parent().data("idx");

    // .change() forces the 'changed' event to trigger.
    $('#' + removal_id).prop('checked', false).change();

    $(this).parent().remove();
});
});
```

This code is attached to a small "X" in the upper right corner of an image.  The image itself is completely outside of DataTables.

This line finds the exact check box that needs to be unchecked and unchecks it, it should then fire the `change` event but that doesn't seem to be working.  It works on whatever page I am on.  But if I am on page 2 and the check box that needs to be unchecked is on page 1, it will uncheck it, but the change event is not fired which i need to be fired.

I have also tried `table.$('#' + removal_id).prop('checked', false).change();` and it does the same thing.  Table referring to the DataTable object.

When I am on the same page as the check box that needs to be unchecked the change event fires correctly.

Any idea what I need to change to make the change event fire when not on the same page as the check box?

Comment: what should happen to the table when the `change` occurs?

Comment: @jonmrich all that code is in place within the `table.on('change'` part of the code and it works normally except in this single instance.  I just need to change event to fire but for simplicity sake it could just `alert('change event');`.  In all other parts `.change()` forces this to work properly but not in the single instance described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **CAUSE**

Elements on other pages do not exist in DOM. Delegated event handler that you use as shown below works only for elements that exist in DOM.

```
table.on('change', '[type="checkbox"]', function(){});
```

> **SOLUTION**

Replace anonymous function with named function for `change` event handler, for example `onCheckboxChange` as shown below.

```
function onCheckboxChange(e){
   console.log(this);
}

// ... skipped ...

table.on('change', '[type="checkbox"]', onCheckboxChange);
```

Then when you need to trigger handle `change` event for the checkbox, use the code below:

```
$('#' + removal_id)
   .prop('checked', false)
   .each(function(){
      onCheckboxChange.call(this);
   });
```

Comment: Not only an answer but reasoning as to why it wasn't working.  Thank you for taking the extra time. :)